# Is it possible to specify the position of a Windows Form controls relative to another AutoSize'd control?

Tags: c#, winforms, autosize, flowlayoutpanel

I have a Windows Form window containing a FlowLayoutPanel, an OK Button, and a Cancel Button. The Form and FlowLayoutPanel both have AutoSize enabled, and the FlowLayoutPanel grows or shinks depending on the items placed in it.

I am trying to figure out how to position the OK and Cancel Buttons in the same row directly below the FlowLayoutPanel. I can't just specify positions for them since the FlowLayoutPanel above them grows and shrinks.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your two buttons in another panel (anything will do).

Then put these two panels in another FlowLayoutPanel which arranges them top to bottom.

Answer (score 3):

Anchoring the buttons to the bottom of the form smells like a solution.  If not, you can throw more panels at the problem but that's fugly.  Simply using the Resize event can do wonders:

```
    private void flowLayoutPanel1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        OKButton.Top = CancelButton.Top = flowLayoutPanel1.Bottom + 10;
    }
```